# How to add an additional data point to an instance of a struct when writing it to a file with Serde?

Tags: csv, rust, serde

A `Person` has a `first_name` and a `last_name`. How do I add a `time` of export to a CSV when writing an instance of `Person` to a CSV?

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate csv;
extern crate serde;

use std::time::{SystemTime, UNIX_EPOCH};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Person {
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
}

fn current_ms() -> u64 {
    let since_the_epoch = &SystemTime::now().duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap();
    let ms = since_the_epoch.as_secs() * 1000 + since_the_epoch.subsec_nanos() as u64 / 1_000_000;
    ms
}

fn main() {
    let person = Person {
        first_name: "Craig".to_string(),
        last_name: "David".to_string(),
    };
    let file_path = std::path::Path::new("test.csv");
    let mut wtr = csv::Writer::from_path(file_path).unwrap();
    wtr.serialize(&person).unwrap();
    println!("{}", current_ms());
}
```

The above code results in:

```
>>> cat test.csv
first_name,last_name
Craig,David
```

My objective is to generate a file which is in the format:

```
>>> cat test.csv
time,first_name,last_name
1527661792118,Craig,David
```

[Serde attributes](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html) do not have an option to add an additional field. In the above example the `Person` struct does not contain a `time` value. The `time` value is only required when the data is written to a CSV.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How to transform fields during serialization using Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39383809/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster I've updated the post to explain why serde attributes do not appear to be a solution.

Comment: Did you read **both** parts of the answer? I know it's a very long answer, but read the part with "to create a separate struct".

Comment: I've reorganized that answer to make it clear that there are two solutions presented.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks! It took a while for me to understand how your solution worked however I got it in the end :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to add a timestamp column to `Person`, you can create a separate struct for that and then join them together in a tuple:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Timestamp {
    time: u64,
}

impl Timestamp {
    fn now() -> Timestamp {
        Timestamp { time: current_ms() }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let person = Person {
        first_name: "Craig".to_string(),
        last_name: "David".to_string(),
    };
    let person_and_time = (Timestamp::now(), person);
    let file_path = std::path::Path::new("test.csv");
    let mut wtr = csv::Writer::from_path(file_path).unwrap();
    wtr.serialize(&person_and_time).unwrap();
}
```