# How to join to another table when serializing a Diesel type?

Tags: rust, serde, rust-diesel

I'm trying to implement a serializer for my struct:

```rust
#[derive(Queryable, Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct One {
    two_id: i32,
}

#[derive(Queryable, Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Two {
    id: i32,
}
```

I'd like to get struct `One` from the database with diesel and print it with serde. I found the [`serialize_with`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#serialize_with) attribute which can be applied to `two_id`. How would I implement such a method with the given interface: `fn<'de, D>(D) -> Result<T, D::Error> where D: Deserializer<'de>` to invoke `json!(get_two_from_db())` on my queried object?

I'd like to be able to call `json!(one)` and automatically get the joined objects.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How to transform fields during serialization using Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39383809/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Alright @Shepmaster the other question gives me the basics to implement is by myself. Thank you, this Question can be marked as already answered.

Comment: That's great your question was answered! Depending on your surrounding program, you may want to think if there are more SQL-efficient ways to get all the data you want in fewer queries (perhaps just one...). It's not always possible, though.