# How do I serialize and deserialize a remote crate's enum as a number?

Tags: rust, serde

I have been trying to setup the following configuration for the [`serialport`](https://docs.rs/serialport/3.3.0/serialport/) crate in Rust with [`serde`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.104/serde/), so I can intuitively supply `7` in my config for `data_bits`, but it will be deserialized as `serialport::DataBits::Seven`. Unfortunately, it seemingly fails the moment I want it to be a number (`7`) and not a string (`seven`).

## Test case

**cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "serde_error"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Jason Miller"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
serialport = "3.3.0"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
ron = "0.5.1"
```

The following results in the error:

```
6:16: Expected identifier
```

**main.rs**

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(remote = "serialport::DataBits")]
pub enum DataBitsDef {
    #[serde(rename = "5")]
    Five,
    #[serde(rename = "6")]
    Six,
    #[serde(rename = "7")]
    Seven,
    #[serde(rename = "8")]
    Eight,
}

fn default_data_bits() -> serialport::DataBits {
    serialport::DataBits::Eight
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct TransceiverSettings {
    pub vid: u16,
    pub pid: u16,
    pub baud_rate: u32,

    #[serde(default = "default_data_bits", with = "DataBitsDef")]
    pub data_bits: serialport::DataBits,
}

impl Default for TransceiverSettings {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            vid: 0x2341,
            pid: 0x0043,
            baud_rate: 115_200,

            data_bits: serialport::DataBits::Eight,
        }
    }
}

const TRX_CONFIG: &str = "
(
    vid: 0x2341,
    pid: 0x0043, 
    baud_rate: 9600,
    data_bits: 7,
)
";

fn main() {
    match ron::de::from_str::<TransceiverSettings>(&TRX_CONFIG) {
        Err(e) => eprintln!("{}", e),
        Ok(c) => println!("{:?}", c),
    }
}
```

Oddly enough, writing `7` as `seven` succeeds and returns:

```
TransceiverSettings { vid: 9025, pid: 67, baud_rate: 9600, data_bits: Seven }
```

**main.rs**

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(remote = "serialport::DataBits")]
pub enum DataBitsDef {
    #[serde(rename = "5")]
    Five,
    #[serde(rename = "6")]
    Six,
    #[serde(rename = "seven")]
    Seven,
    #[serde(rename = "8")]
    Eight,
}

fn default_data_bits() -> serialport::DataBits {
    serialport::DataBits::Eight
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct TransceiverSettings {
    pub vid: u16,
    pub pid: u16,
    pub baud_rate: u32,

    #[serde(default = "default_data_bits", with = "DataBitsDef")]
    pub data_bits: serialport::DataBits,
}

impl Default for TransceiverSettings {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            vid: 0x2341,
            pid: 0x0043,
            baud_rate: 115_200,

            data_bits: serialport::DataBits::Eight,
        }
    }
}

const TRX_CONFIG: &str = "
(
    vid: 0x2341,
    pid: 0x0043, 
    baud_rate: 9600,
    data_bits: seven,
)
";

fn main() {
    match ron::de::from_str::<TransceiverSettings>(&TRX_CONFIG) {
        Err(e) => eprintln!("{}", e),
        Ok(c) => println!("{:?}", c),
    }
}
```

## serde_repr

One of the given examples in the `serde` [documentation](https://serde.rs/enum-number.html) seems relevant to my case, but I haven't managed to get it working with my setup.

> [**Serialize enum as number**](https://serde.rs/enum-number.html#serialize-enum-as-number)
>   The `serde_repr` crate provides alternative derive macros that derive the same Serialize and Deserialize traits but delegate to the underlying representation of a C-like enum. This allows C-like enums to be formatted as integers rather than strings in JSON
>
> ```
> #[derive(Serialize_repr, Deserialize_repr, PartialEq, Debug)]
> #[repr(u8)]
> enum SmallPrime {
>     Two = 2,
>     Three = 3,
>     Five = 5,
>     Seven = 7,
> }
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Support for `#[serde(remote)]` is [not present](https://github.com/dtolnay/serde-repr/blob/0.1.5/src/parse.rs#L23-L33) in serde_repr 0.1.5. You will need to submit a pull request or issue to add support for it.

Instead, follow the advice in [How to transform fields during deserialization using Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46753955/155423) and [How to transform fields during serialization using Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39383809/155423):

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

mod shim {
    use serde::{de::Error, Deserialize, Deserializer, Serialize, Serializer};
    use serialport::DataBits;

    pub fn serialize<S>(v: &DataBits, s: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        use DataBits::*;

        let v: u8 = match v {
            Five => 5,
            Six => 6,
            Seven => 7,
            Eight => 8,
        };

        v.serialize(s)
    }

    pub fn deserialize<'de, D>(d: D) -> Result<DataBits, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        use DataBits::*;

        match u8::deserialize(d)? {
            5 => Ok(Five),
            6 => Ok(Six),
            7 => Ok(Seven),
            8 => Ok(Eight),
            o => Err(D::Error::custom(format_args!("Invalid value {}", o))),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct TransceiverSettings {
    pub vid: u16,
    pub pid: u16,
    pub baud_rate: u32,

    #[serde(default = "default_data_bits", with = "shim")]
    pub data_bits: serialport::DataBits,
}
```

Comment: That's a wonderful solution! I've looked at [`serialize_with`](https://serde.rs/variant-attrs.html#serialize_with) and [`deserialize_with`](https://serde.rs/variant-attrs.html#deserialize_with) and couldn't wrap my head around it until now. I could even extend this for the `baud_rate` now,  with only select values being valid. Thank you!