# How to serialize options to JSON as arrays

Tags: rust, serde

I am working in a relatively large codebase where options are represented in JSON as arrays, so `None` is represented in JSON as `[]` and `Some(thing)` as `[thing]`.  (Yes, the codebase also contains Haskell, in case you are wondering.)  How can I override the default `serde_json` behaviour, which is to omit optional fields, to match this?

E.g. a struct:

```
SomeData {
  foo: Some(1),
  bar: None
}
```

should be serialized to JSON as:

```
{
  "foo": [1],
  "bar": []
}
```

Of course, one could theoretically implement custom serialization for each and every optional field in every struct that interacts with the codebase but that would be a huge undertaking, even if it were possible.

There don't seem to be any options in [the serde_json serialisation of some and none](https://github.com/serde-rs/json/blob/993e7a6eeaa89b39329d245e63879d7913ed1a41/src/ser.rs#L269) so I imagine that the solution will be creating a new serializer that inherits almost everything from `serde_json` apart from the Option serialization and deserialization.  Are there any examples of projects that do this?  It would also be possible to make a fork but maintaining a fork is never much fun.

Comment: Can you annotate the optional fields in an attribute, or use a custom non-`Option` type for them?

Comment: Precisely this would be "the huge undertaking" and would be error prone, as any new type that was added or imported anywhere would have to have the same annotations added.

Comment: Can you add one attribute to each struct, on top?

Comment: If you need to modify structs you don't control (i.e., imported ones), you will not be able to avoid writing a custom `Serializer`. You might be able to implement it as a wrapper around another one, e.g., the existing one in `serde_json`. You basically overwrite the `serialize_none` and `serialize_some` functions to emit arrays instead of the default behavior. This is not super complicated but quite boilerplate heavy.

Answer (score 2):

> Of course, one could theoretically implement custom serialization for each and every optional field in every struct that interacts with the codebase

A custom implementation for *each and every field* is not necessary. By using [`serialize_with`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#serialize_with), you only need one transformation function describing the serialization of any serializable `Option<T>` as a sequence.

```rust
fn serialize_option_as_array<T, S>(value: &Option<T>, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
where
    T: Serialize,
    S: Serializer,
{
    let len = if value.is_some() { 1 } else { 0 };
    let mut seq = serializer.serialize_seq(Some(len))?;
    for element in value {
        seq.serialize_element(element)?;
    }
    seq.end()
}
```

Using it in your struct:

```
use serde_derive::Serialize;
use serde::ser::{Serialize, Serializer, SerializeSeq};
use serde_json;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
struct SomeData {
    #[serde(serialize_with = "serialize_option_as_array")]
    foo: Option<i32>,
    #[serde(serialize_with = "serialize_option_as_array")]
    bar: Option<u32>,
}


let data = SomeData {
    foo: Some(5),
    bar: None,
};

println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&data)?);
```

The output:

```json
{"foo":[5],"bar":[]}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e2696763c8e05e076e2e942711a55cd7)

See also:

- [How to transform fields during serialization using Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383809/how-to-transform-fields-during-serialization-using-serde)

Comment: The OP said they cannot annotate each field.

Comment: Correct, unfortunately that will not be enough but I appreciate the input. Perhaps it will help someone else in a similar position.